# phonegap iframe youtube video embed blank screen only audio

Tags: iframe, phonegap

I am developing a Phonegap application. I want to play Youtube video in a page along with some text content. I used `iframe` and video is playing, pausing, full-screen but I get only sound. There is no video only a black screen.

```
iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height ="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameBorder="0"
```

Please do help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube is providing the youtube player API. I used this API in phonegap API and its working fine.
Here is the code.

```
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

And in html file

```
<body>
   <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
   <div id="player"></div>
</body>
```

It's working fine in my phonegap app.
You can try this.

Comment: I tried using the code. Still I get blank screen and only audio. I tried with my video ID. I get error 'An error occurred. Please try again later'. I am not sure where I am going wrong.